# Youtube onStateChange doesn't work after load a new video

Tags: youtube

I created a Youtube player and added a onStateChange listener, it works for the first video.

```
var o = new Object;
o.videoId = 'videoid1';
player = new YT.Player('div1', o);
player.addEventListener("onStateChange", "stateChangeListener", false);

function stateChangeListener(e) {
    console.log(e.data);
}
```

But after load a new video, onStateChange event doesn't fire anymore.

```
function nextVideo() {
    player.cueVideoById('div2');
}
```

Even if I added a new listener to it.

```
function nextVideo() {
    player.cueVideoById('div2');
    player.addEventListener("onStateChange", "stateChangeListener", false);
}
```

What's the problem? How to fire onStateChange event if there're many videos on one page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is it doesn't attach the event handler to the correct Youtube player.

```html
<iframe id="video" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XXXX"></iframe>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XXXX" />
```